# How should one design a modular mobile application?

Tags: design, android, ios

I'm currently working on a native mobile solution where I need to design a modular application.

Imagine a scenario where you have your core application and 3 supporting modules.

You can either sell your entire application or your client can negotiate and select what modules are more important. Your client might also want to buy the module separately.

[image]

From a developer point of view, each module represents a different project and the core application must be designed to support them one-by-one.

What are the best design solutions that I should look for when developing this with `Android Studio` and `XCode`?

Should I integrate each module in the project as libraries and make the Main Project independent?

Comment: is this for iOS? You may have some limitations with how you are allowed to distribute this through the app store.

Comment: This is both for `iOS` and `Android`platforms. The application in the store will have all modules enabled.

Comment: If you have a pluggable core then I'd treat modules/plugins as independent projects which can be deployed independently of the core or other modules.